# Basic authentication with HttpClient in C# without hardcoding password

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, basic-authentication

I am invoking an API with System.Net.Http.HttpClient and is using Basic Authentication. The client is running as a windows service. 
I am looking for a way to trigger the API with basic authentication.

I know I can use something like

`var base64String=;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", EncodeBase64(GetBytes("username:password")));`

I don't want to input , username & pasword or base 64 encoded credentials. Is it possible to get the credentials of current user, so that the credentials are not maintained in the app(in config files or code).

I don't want to maintain credentials in the application, since it is a tedious process during set up to edit the config file(or wherever the credentials are maintained) and add the credentials, also it is not secure to have credentials in the config file as it is human readable.

Comment: That's what basic authentication means - passing the username/password like this. Nothing forces you to hard-code those values, they can come from a configuration file, or profile settings but in the end, you have to send them. If you don't want that, don't use basic authentication

Comment: `Is it possible to get the credentials of current user` that's how windows/domain authentication works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree to you. But I am trying to find how this can be done with HttpClient. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You already wrote the relevant code in the question. Are you asking how to load settings from configuration? You could even load them from a local file. Have you looked at .NET Core's configuration classes?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not asking on how to get the configuration. But trying to see how to use credentials without saving it anywhere, as it will be tedious to input credentials in a config file and is not secure. I will edit the question with this information.

Comment: this won't change the answers - that's not how basic authentication works. If you don't want stored credentials, ask the user. If you don't want to ask the user, store the credentials. You *can* store them securely by the way, and the .NET Core docs show how to do that. Configuration settings don't have to be stored in files, and even when they are, they don't have to be unencrypted. Besides, are you going to call the API with *end user* credentials? Which means that API already has access to all users' passwords?

Comment: Asking the user is not possible here as my API client will be running as a windows service. A service account will be running this. I am trying to see if I can get the credentials of that user. Someone has down voted my question.

Comment: you *can't* get the service account's password. That's the whole point of accounts, and what *you* ask to do with the API. If you want to use the service account, you *have* to use Windows authentication. If you can't you need to store the credentials and possibly the authentication tokens securely. Secure storage per account is available since 2000.

Comment: The [ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.0) section shows how you can store credentials securely. The [Secrets management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=windows) shows how to handle credentials specifically in development and production. You don't need to use the Azure Key Vault provider shown in that example by the way

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you not to hard code these credentials and preferably to get them from things such as a database where they are safely hashed. If you simply don't want to input the username & password or the base 64 encoded equivalant, then I suggest you look into other options aside from basic authentication.

Other options could be windows authentication, azure or even client certificates.

Comment: I am consuming an API,which is not in my control.I cannot change the authentication method.

Comment: @Ajith you control where the credentials are stored though. Frankly, this question is unclear. Nothing forces you to hard-code the credentials

Comment: I don't want to add the credentials in config file as it will be human readable, which can potentially compromise the password also configuring credentials will add overhead to the set up process. Someone has down voted my question.

Comment: Not able to change the auth method is a discussion in itself. You agree with that you do not want to hard code the credentials somewhere in the configs which is good. But like Panagiotis mentioned, you can control where they are stored. Where are these credentials coming from? If you have multiple users then why should they be in the configs? Why not just place them in a database where they can be hashed and not human readable. In the code where you need these credentials, you can just call the credentials from the database based on user session and now they aren't hardcoded anymore.